# How to generate database without php symfony/bin command?

Tags: php, symfony

I wrote and entity, a controller and a view and I want to link the whole thing to a database so that I can consult my input.

However, I can't get access to the commands `php symfony/console` or `php symfony/bin`.

Do you have any idea on how can I generate my database without those commands, so that I can work on it and start to work on my design?

Comment: Even with a vm you can use `php bin/console`. Why you can't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you have mysql installed in your local machine, so you can just connect through your bash terminal by typing:

```
mysql -u your_db_user_here -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -p
```

It will prompt with a password input, type your database user's password

If you still don't have a database user, log in as root user

```
mysql -u your_root_user_here -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -p
```

It will prompt with a password input, type your database root's password

Once logged in, you can create your database by typing

```
mysql> create database your_db_name_here
```

And now you have a database created

Answer (score 2):

Almost any `sf` shell command can be also executed from `PHP` code:

```
$application = new Application($kernel);
$application->setAutoExit(false);

$input = new ArrayInput(array(
    'command' => 'doctrine:schema:update',
    // (optional) pass options to the command
    '--dump-sql' => true,
));

$output = new BufferedOutput();
$application->run($input, $output);
```

You can find more details [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/command_in_controller.html).

Comment: Cool - did not know that :)

Comment: Make sure to get the kernel from the container. Do not boot a new one.